# Бюст героя или бюст герою?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, существительные

Как правильно: *возложить цветы к бюсту **героя*** или *к бюсту **герою**?*

Comment: Я так и думала! Большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Существительное [БЮСТ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_26) в значении «скульптурное изображение головы и верхней части человеческого тела (по грудь или по пояс)» **управляет родительным падежом**:

бюст **кого (чей)** — бюст Пирогова, бюст Пушкина, бюст великого мыслителя, бюст героя; *возложить цветы **к бюсту героя.***

Часто встречающееся неправильное управление с дательным падежом ("бюст герою") возникает на основе ложной аналогии: **памятник** (кому?) **герою.**

*Над **бюстом героя** скульптор Першудчев начал работать еще в госпитале...*

**Бюст героя** Отечественной войны донского атамана генерала Матвея Платова; церемония возложения цветов **к бюсту героя.**

Answer (score 0):

К бюсту героя.
Бюст - чей, памятник - кому.
Хотя иногда наблюдаются окказиональные колебания, нормативными их признать не могу.