# Замужество — «с» или «за»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Только что прочел в публикации вполне солидного новостного издания предложение:

> Ей приходилось врать и отрицать факт замужества за первым супругом.

Поймал себя на том, что я скорее всего написал бы "факт замужества **с** первым супругом".
А затем задумался: как же все-таки правильно? Понятно, что *замужем **за***, но *брак **с***.
А вот как быть с *замужеством*?

Comment: «Замужество за первым супругом» также несуразно, как «жена от первого брака». Это или 16 полоса, или 6 палата.

Comment: @shampar, это lenta.ru. У них, по идее, должен быть вполне вменяемый штат редакторов/корректоров.

Comment: Давно есть желание открыть на сайте рубрику типа «Идиотеки» А. Лебедева — копилки словесной перемудрости.

Comment: Это сайт вопросов и ответов, ничего другого здесь быть не может.

Comment: Так к каждому перлу приложить знак вопроса не вопрос.

Comment: Ответ обновлен.

Comment: @oleedd, я добавил мой голос также и за Ваш ответ, т.к. Вы обратили внимание на интересный нюанс, но в качестве принятого ответа все же оставляю ответ Риммы Михайловой, как наиболее полный и обстоятельный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Словари](https://endic.ru/ozhegov/Zamuzhestvo-9250.html) однозначно говорят, что правильно с предлогом "с":
Ушаков — состоять в замужестве **с** кем-нибудь;
Кузнецов —  замужество **с** кем-либо.

Интересна статистика Нацкорпуса.
[Замужество **с**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=1&req=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%81&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform) — 32 результата (17 — XX век, остальные — XIX век).
[Замужество **за**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform) — 32 результата (2 — XXI век, 3 — XX век, остальные — XIX и XVIII).

Предполагаю, что форма "замужество за" была **нормой** до середины XIX века.

Затем установка поменялась в сторону "замужества с". Вот первые вхождения:

**Замужество с сыном** императрицы Екатерины открыло ей доступ ко двору, а высшие качества и пленительный ум не замедлили всех к ней привязать. [М. А. Корф. Записки (**1838-1852**)]
Все выгоды на твоей стороне ― и всё это чрез **замужество с князем**. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Дядюшкин сон (**1858-1859**)]
Ведь он, по-видимому, вполне убежден, что **замужество с Вихоревым** составит гибель его дочери. [Н. А. Добролюбов. Темное царство (**1859**)]

Comment: Вполне возможно, что здесь происходит путаница, чем-то похожая на *бюст — памятник* (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/%d0%91%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8e): бюст героя — памятник герою.

Answer (score 1):

У меня звучит (здесь). На целесообразность влияет глагол:
***Состоять с** кем-нибудь в замужестве.* || Здесь уже "за" вообще не подходит.

В Гугл "*факт замужества за*" более чем в два раза чаще, чем С. В основном это новости:
[https://www.google.com/search?q="факт+замужества+за"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%22)

Связано с тем, что при образовании другой части речи удобно сохранять предлог. Язык же развивается, меняется.

Когда предлог С, появляется двусмысленность:
*врать и отрицать факт с первым супругом*.
Возможно, поэтому у меня С не звучит именно в этом примере.

Comment: Мне кажется, что-то Вы тут напутали: *врать и отрицать факт с первым супругом.* Врать факт — неверно, и замужество пропустили. Врать о факте замужества с первым супругом. Отрицать факт замужества с первым супругом.

Comment: Хочу обратить внимание на то, что "врать и отрицать факт" в оригинале, это не моё. "Замужество" необходимо пропустить, чтобы остался только второй смысл.